# Sum multiple multiindex column dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a dataframe like

```
  0       1             One                       Two
Tech    Tool    First  Second  Third      First  Second  Third
Auto     UIP     23      18      5          59     56      3
 AI      ALT     45      34      11         32     12      20
```

Need an output like

```
  0       1             One                       Two                      Sum
Tech    Tool    First  Second  Third      First  Second  Third    First   Second    Third
Auto     UIP     23      18      5          59     56      3        82      74        8
 AI      ALT     45      34      11         32     12      20       77      46        31
```

Here for Sum  First 82=23+59, Second 74=18+56, Third 8=5+3
Similarly for others. I am beginner in multiindex dataframe please help

Comment: `df.groupby(level=1, axis=1).sum()`?

Comment: @ash can you provide code that generates your example dataframe?

Comment: I import this file from external source in html format then i convert this into dataframe. So i don't have code to generate this dataframe

Comment: I'm saying you need to _write_ that code and provide it here

Comment: See here for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
df.groupby(level=1, axis=1).sum()
```